# What does this quote by Thoreau mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

> His vote is of no more worth than that of any unprincipled foreigner
>   or hireling native, who may have been bought. **Oh for a man who is a
>   man, and, as my neighbor says, has a bone in his back which you cannot
>   pass your hand through!**

How to understand the sentence in bold? Where's the subject in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Oh

This is a simple interjection.  Thoreau is expressing exasperation.

> for

This is an *elision*.  The full expression is "What I would not give for...", meaning "I really want..."  Thoreau is shortening it to just the last word.

> a man who is a man,

that is, a man who is a *real* man, and not a "unprincipled foreigner or hireling native" (kinda racist, but what are you going to do?)

> and, as my neighbor says,

His neighbor uses a colloquial expression, which he will now quote

> has a bone in his back which you cannot pass your hand through!

In modern English, we say a man has a "spine" or "backbone"; figuratively, he is stalwart and courageous.  The imagery here is that a weak man's backbone is not missing, but is insubstantial, like a column of smoke or a stream of water, and you could put ("pass") your hand through it.

Comment: So the subject is "I" and it has been hidden from the sentence, "I really want my fellow men to be stalwart." Is it right?

Comment: In the question, "What would I not do to find a real man?", the subject is -- I believe -- _what_, rather than _I_, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

> Oh for a man who is a man

Introduction, he is making a definition of what being a *man* is

> and, as my neighbor says

as his neighbor suggests

> has a bone in his back which you cannot pass your hand through!

"*a man*" will have a *strong* backbone.

A person who is describes as having a *weak* backbone will not have a *strength of character* or *strong integrity* to stand up to opposition/challenges. They might be described as being

> spineless

which is weak both physically and morally.